# Table captions do not appear on top in IEEETran class

Tags: lyx, ieeetran

I'm writing a journal using IEEE Transactions class. I am using the default settings but the table captions still appear at the bottom of the table.

Ive performed a search and the problem most people have is that Table is not written in uppercase. In my case TABLE is written in uppercase but appear at the bottom of the table.

Below is a screenshot of my settings:

[image]

Ive also followed the solutions from other questions and have ensured that Language Package is set to None.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IEEETran is here meaningless. Important is the position of `\caption`. Please compare:

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Table title.}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|l|}\hline

$4$ & $3$ & $\neq 0$ & Surface 1 \\
$4$ & $3$ & $<0$ & Surface 1 \\
$4$ & $3$ & $>0$ & Surface 1 \\
$4$ & $2$ & $<0$ & Surface 1 \\
$4$ & $2$ & $>0$ & Surface 1 \\
$3$ & $3$ & & Surface 1 \\
$3$ & $2$ & & Surface 1 \\
$3$ & $2$ & & Surface 1 \\
$3$ & $1$ & & Surface 1 \\
$2$ & $1$ & & Surface 1 \\
$2$ & $1$ & & Surface 1 \\
$1$ & $1$ & & Surface 1 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
%\caption{Table title.}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|l|}\hline

$4$ & $3$ & $\neq 0$ & Surface 1 \\
$4$ & $3$ & $<0$ & Surface 1 \\
$4$ & $3$ & $>0$ & Surface 1 \\
$4$ & $2$ & $<0$ & Surface 1 \\
$4$ & $2$ & $>0$ & Surface 1 \\
$3$ & $3$ & & Surface 1 \\
$3$ & $2$ & & Surface 1 \\
$3$ & $2$ & & Surface 1 \\
$3$ & $1$ & & Surface 1 \\
$2$ & $1$ & & Surface 1 \\
$2$ & $1$ & & Surface 1 \\
$1$ & $1$ & & Surface 1 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table title.}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\vfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But how do I edit this in LyX? Should I be adding all my Tables using the LaTeX source box?

Comment: @StuckInPhD No, that's not necessary. But you can add the tabular either before or after the caption. Or cut/paste to move an existing table or caption.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks, I added the ``\caption`` above my table in Lyx and it created the desired output, but LyX's own float caption persists. In output I have ``new caption`` - Table - ``Lyx old caption``. If old caption is left empty it still comes up as ``Table II``. how to avoid this?

Comment: @StuckInPhD Don't add a second caption in an ERT. You can cut and paste the LyX caption like you would cut and paste anything else, but you need to select the caption box itself, not the text inside it. That the caption is there by default when you insert a table float, doesn't mean that it's fixed, you can delete it or move it. (And new captions in a float are inserted with Insert -> Caption, no need for ERT there either.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you. That solved it. Another issue unrelated to my current question is that my Table title is not broken up into two lines, like whats its supposed to look like in IEEETran is ``Table I``-``\newline``-``Table Caption``. What I have is ``Table I: Table Caption``. Can I fix this? Many thanks

Comment: @StuckInPhD Unrelated => Ask new question. I don't know why anyway.