# Where one can find an old version of `table` environment

Tags: sourcecode

This question is a result of an answer to [Table captions do not appear on top in IEEETran class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395284/table-captions-do-not-appear-on-top-in-ieeetran-class)

As far as I remember, a long time ago the caption for a table was always in a proper position. It was independent on the relative position of `\caption` to the rest (generally, `tabular`).

Is there any chance to find this early (in my opinion: better) version somewhere?

Comment: Do you mean in previous LaTeX releases?

Comment: Are packages allowed?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes. And the suggestion, when the change was made, would be perfect. About 15 years ago the version in question was used.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: Well, older releases of TL are available: ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/, but I can't suggest the precise time of change.

Comment: @TeXnician I can write some version of it, so an additional package is not the best solution. I am rather interested in reminding, how it was obtained in some earlier version of `latex.ltx` (or maybe `latex.tex`).

Comment: See also: http://www.latex-project.org/get/#historic

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: I found a TL5c CDROM from 2000 (which is earlier than 15 years ago) in my shelves. I can zip the latex - base directory and sent it to you (provided I have some contact address) or place it in my DropBox, enabling free download

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Oh, it may be a good solution, if the developers of LaTeX wont't answer here. My e-mail (or email, as Donald Knuth wants) is standard: Przemyslaw.Scherwentke@pwr.edu.pl

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: Mail sent

Comment: You presumably mean to ask for an old version of the IEEE class, not an old version of latex (latex does not position captions at all)

Answer (score 6):

The handling of caption has never changed in latex: the code for `\caption` and `\@caption` has literally not changed at all since we started the current svn in 2008, I didn't check back beyond that but essentially it hasn't changed since latex2.09, 30 years ago.

The caption is just set where it appears in the source file. This is really the only possibility if you allow authors to have multiple captions in the same `table` or position the captions to the side in `minipage` or other formatting rules.

Some packages and classes use a more controlled format where only one caption is allowed and it is saved by the float mechanism rather than being typeset and then positioned according to some document options. Notably any document using the `float` package (or a class that uses `float`) has the possibility of the float mechanism taking over caption positioning via that package's `\restylefloat` command.

---

But as Christian mentioned in comments, if you want to look at old copies of latex for other reasons, then http://www.latex-project.org/get/#historic has some links.

Comment: I suggested the historic versions only in case LaTeX is the 'culprit', but I think you're right that `IEEETran` is to blame about the change.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yep but I was aware that my answer originally  didn't answer the question as asked in the title so I added your comment again, although actually most browsers don't seem to want to follow ftp links these days....